# Increasing Week Number for different dates in different years

Tags: r, date, datetime, dataframe

I have dates from two years - 2012 and 2013. I have the dates arranged in ascending order in a data frame, but they repeat after a while based on some other criterion. I would like to add another column to the data frame with increasing week numbers.

I came up with the code that achieves the following:

```
Date    WeekNumber
12/31/2012  53
12/31/2012  53
12/31/2012  1
1/1/2013    1
1/1/2013    1
12/31/2012  53
12/31/2012  53
```

I want something that achieves the following:

```
 Date   WeekNumber
12/31/2012  1
12/31/2012  1
12/31/2012  2
1/1/2013    2
1/1/2013    2
12/31/2012  1
12/31/2012  1
```

I want the week numbers to increase after a certain date (2012-01-01, say). The format of the 'Date' column is `Date`.

Comment: Can you specify more clearly what the `WeekNumber` would be logically? At a minimum, the 3rd line in your latter data is a typo that should be `1` (since that line is identical to the 2 above it), but what does it mean that the last day of the year is the 1st week of the year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your data are ordered in a very strange way... Still, assuming you have something of this kind,

```
Date    WeekNumber
12/31/2012  53
1/1/2013    1
12/31/2013  53
1/1/2014    1
12/31/2014  53
```

You can run

```
data <- read.table("stack.txt", sep="\t", header=TRUE)
year <- function(date){
    as.numeric(format(as.POSIXct(date, format="%m/%d/%Y"), format="%Y"))
}
FirstYear <- year(data$Date[1])
data$WeekNumber <- data$WeekNumber  + 53*(year(data$Date) - FirstYear)
# And add if you want ...
# data$WeekNumber <- data$WeekNumber - 53
```

and get

```
Date    WeekNumber
12/31/2012  53
1/1/2013    54
12/31/2013  106
1/1/2014    107
12/31/2014  159
```